# git reset --hard equivalent on bare repository

Tags: git, git-bare

After last commit my team decided remote has grown too heavy and would be better to make a new one to split tasks between asset testing (heavy repo) and functionality testing (light repo).
So I made a push --mirror and created a new repo, but it is still affected by a last commit and appears to be too heavy.
Is it possible to revert last commit on a new repository before cloning to local machine? (since all heavy assets added with the last commit are unuseful for new repo)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command

```
git push -f . commit:branch
```

can achieve the same effect on a bare repository by resetting the branch named "branch" to point to commit `commit`.

Note that it works in normal repositories, too, except for cases where the branch you're about to reposition is currently checked out and the commit `HEAD` points at is not `commit`.

There's also the `git update-ref` command but I'd say it's too low level to use under "normal" circumstances.

Comment: Thanks, that followed with a git gc --prune=now did the trick perfectly.